# Column or expression in SELECT list not valid

Tags: sql, odbc

I get this error:

> [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0122 - Column CDSTYL or expression in SELECT list not valid.

when I try and run the below query.

`CDSTYL` is a valid column in `CDCART00`.

I am uncertain what the issue is. The SQL is part of an inventory management system I am trying to get data from.

```
select 
    x.item,
    x.lot,
    sum(x.case_qty) lpn_inv_ttl,
    sum(x.carton_qty) carton_ttl,
    sum(x.sku_invn) sku_inv_ttl,
    sum(x.case_qty)+sum(x.carton_qty) - sum(x.sku_invn) inv_discrepany
from
    (select 
         IDSTYL as Item,
         IDBCHN as Lot,
         IDQTY as case_qty,
         0 sku_invn,
         0 as carton_qty
     from 
         idcase00
     where 
         IDSTAT in ('30', '50', '55', '60', '65', '90')

     union all

     select
         CDSTYL as Item,
         cdbchn as Lot,
         0 as case_qty,
         0 as sku_invn,
         sum(cdpaku) as carton_qty
     from 
         chcart00
     join 
         CDCART00 on chcasn = cdcasn
     where 
         chstat < '85'

     union all

     select 
         SKSTYL as Item, 
         SKBCHN as Lot,
         0 as case_qty,
         (SKAOHQ + SKUOHQ) AS sku_invn,
         0 as carton_qty
     from 
         SKINVN00) X
group by 
    x.item, x.lot
having 
    sum(x.case_qty) + sum(x.carton_qty) != sum(x.sku_invn)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (sql-server, MySQL, etc.)

Comment: Have you tried running each select independently to see if you get any errors?

Comment: Do `IDSTYL` and `CDSTYL` columns have the same type ?

Comment: based on the error text, It's not sql-server.

Comment: @Rominus - Not exactly sure. See edit in original post.

Comment: @krokodilko Yes

Answer (score 3):

You need a group by:

```
select CDSTYL as Item,
                            cdbchn as Lot,
                            0 as case_qty,
                            0 as sku_invn,
                            sum(cdpaku) as carton_qty
                            from chcart00
                            join CDCART00
                            on chcasn = cdcasn
                            where chstat < '85'
group by CDSTYL ,cdbchn
```

Comment: The `GROUP BY` should also include `CDSTYL`

Comment: I didn't see that because of formatting but you are correct

Comment: Fabulous... Works...  `group by CDSTYL,CDBCHN`